# DJANGO 3.2 wont load images from declared media folder 404 error

Tags: django, django-templates

#urs.py

```
urlpatterns = [ ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

#setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

#model

```
images = models.ImageField(upload_to='BonusVilla/image/', blank=True)
```

#tempalte

```
{%for i in images%}
    <img  src="{{ i.images.url }}" />
{%endfor%}
```

#the browser it renders this

```
<img src="/media/BonusVilla/image/apple_3H8ByYb.jpg">
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: I have done everything that was required in that documentation, still nothing. Im not sure  what is wrong

Comment: provide more details on `model.py`, `views.py` and the template file.